# Best way to make a periodic WS call to feed an Enumerator with Play2/Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, enumerator, loops

I use the Enumerator pattern to retrieve some tweets every second with WS.url

```
Enumerator.fromCallback[String](() => 
        Promise.timeout(WS.url("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q="+query+"&rpp=1").get().map { response =>
            val tweets = response.json \\ "text"
            tweets match {
                case Nil => "Nothing found!"
                case head :: tail => query + " : " + head.as[String]
            }
        }.map(Some.apply).value.get, 1000 milliseconds)
  )
```

My is problem is that

```
Enumerator.fromCallback[String]()
```

is waiting for a

```
Promise[Option[String]]
```

As WS.url(...).get returns a Promise, and as I use Promise.timeout to re-launch the call every second,

I have a

```
Promise[Promise[Option[String]]]
```

So I have to use value.get to have the good type, so it does not seems very clean for the asynchronous aspect.

This code works but my question is : Is there a better way, more elegant, to achieve this?
Can I get easily a Promise from another Promise and a Promise.timeout?

Thanks :)

Comment: Out of question, you should have a look at Twitter streaming API. We first started croning requests on TT Search and ended with the streaming API : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Promise` is a monad, and in general when you find yourself with a nested monad you want to stick a `flatMap` in there somewhere. In your case something like this should work:

```
import akka.util.duration._
import play.api.libs.concurrent._
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import play.api.libs.ws._

val query = "test"
val url = WS.url("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" + query + "&rpp=1")

val tweets = Enumerator.fromCallback[String](() => 
  Promise.timeout(url.get, 1000 milliseconds).flatMap(_.map { response =>
    (response.json \\ "text") match {
      case Nil => "Nothing found!"
      case head :: _ => query + " : " + head.as[String]
    }
  }.map(Some.apply))
)
```

I'd personally write it more like this:

```
val tweets = Enumerator.fromCallback[String](() => 
  Promise.timeout(url.get, 1000 milliseconds).flatMap(_.map(
    _.json.\\("text").headOption.map(query + " " + _.as[String])
  ))
)
```

And not fuss with the `"Nothing found!"` message, but depending on what exactly you're doing that might not be appropriate.